# How is confidence interval computed in statsmodels for ARIMA(p,d,q) parameters?

Tags: python, confidence-interval, statsmodels

I am using statsmodel package for fitting `ARIMA(p,d,q)` model to a time series. My question is how exactly does this package estimate confidence intervals of the parameters of this model? `statsmodels` documentation says that

"The confidence interval is based on the standard normal distribution if self.use_t is False. If self.use_t is True, then uses a Student’s t with self.df_resid_inference (or self.df_resid if df_resid_inference is not defined) degrees of freedom."

Then the question is how is the variance of different parameters estimated to apply the standard Normal or t-distribution method?

Edit: I used the Hessian matrix method to compute the covariance matrix. But the confidence interval obtained using my approach are much wider than those produced by `statsmodels`. Which means that `statsmodels` is not using the Hessian matrix approach. Also, I noticed that as I increase the length of my time-series, the confidence intervals obtained by these approaches become similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the `cov_type` argument to `fit`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.fit) method describes the options for computing the covariance matrix associated with the parameter estimates.

The default method is the outer product of gradients estimator (`cov_type='opg'`).

If you want to use the numerically approximated Hessian, you can choose `cov_type='approx'`, but note that by default this will use complex step differentiation rather than finite differences, so it may still be different from what you compute by hand.